# How come Chrome is not painting partial DOM updates?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, rendering

I'm trying to learn better how Chrome (and other browsers) are rendering pages. I do have some good understanding now of how DOM and CSSOM are constructed. Also, I know a bit about processes of performing Layout and Paint phases.

I tried the following idea:

- try rendering 1000 items created by regular calls to DOM API
- each item is placed inside a `<div>` element (floated left) and appended to `<body>`
- this takes around 1000ms based on `timing.js` output (tool from Addy Osmani) and it's also visible inside the `Timeline` in chrome

JS Fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4oo6nLs/). Sorry for the quality of this example, but I was drafting this in a hurry.

Based on Timeline analysis I figured out that each `<div>` is laid out before the first `Paint` occurs. This is certainly not what I want, because only first 10 are visible on screen after page loads.

So I figured that I will first render initial 10 items which I have hoped will cause `Paint`. Right after that (wrapping the call in `setTimeout(function(){},0)`) I'm appending the rest 990 items to the body.

I was hoping to have the `Paint` method to happen right after initial 10 items are laid out, but that doesn't happen. I can see two `Layout` phases and the `Paint` happens after all 1000 items are laid out. Any ideas where did I go wrong here?

[image: Timeline output]